# ASP.NET MEF Compose all class parts

Tags: asp.net, mef

```
    // In Global asax

    DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin"));

    CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

   // do not want to compose at every instance when use Import attribute.
    container.ComposeParts(this);

    // add all external library (.dll)
    container.ComposeParts(container);


    // Index.aspx page
    public partial Index: Page{

    [Import]
    private c1 object1;

    protected void OnLoadPage
    {
        if (object1== null)
           thrown Error("mef failed, why")
    }

    }


    // External library Library1
    [Export(typeOf(c1))]
    public class c1{}

    // External library Library2
    [Export(typeOf(c2))]
    public class c2{}
```

**why object1 is null?**

How to compose all classes from Global asax or simple to make some asp.net bootstrap lazy loading?

I do not want in every constructor to compose part. How to make all assembly or classes to be compose at the beginning in Global asax? All my [Export] are in external library classes. Main site project have reference to all .dll projects.

I am not sure the my question is correct, sorry for that.

Project is simple asp.net (no MVC) with external library with user controls.